# Device-side enqueue causes CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, amd-gpu

I have a program utilizing OpenCL 2.0 because I want to take advantage of device-side enqueue. I have a test program that performs the following tasks on the host side:

1. Allocates 16 kilobytes of floating point memory on the device and zeros it out.
2. Builds the OpenCL program below, and creates a kernel of `masterKernel()`
3. Sets the first argument of `masterKernel()` (`heap`) to the allocated memory in step 1
4. Enqueues that `masterKernel()` via `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` with a `work_dim` of 1 and a global work size of 1. (So it only runs once, with `get_global_id(0)` always being zero)
5. Reads the memory back into the host and displays it.

Here is the OpenCL code:

```c
//This function was stripped down to nothing for testing purposes.
kernel void childKernel(global float* heap)
{
}

//Enqueues the child kernel.
kernel void masterKernel(global float* heap)
{
    ndrange_t ndRange = ndrange_1D(16);   //Arbitrary, could be any number.

    if(get_global_id(0) == 0)
    {
         enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), 0, ndRange, 
            ^{ childKernel(heap); });   
    }
}
```

The program builds successfully. However, when I try to run `masterKernel()`, The call to `enqueue_kernel()` here causes the *host side* call to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` to fail with an error code of `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES`. OpenCL's documentation says `enqueue_kernel()` should return `CL_SUCCESS` or `CL_ENQUEUE_FAILURE` depending on if the block enqueues successfully or not. It does not say that `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` itself should fail. Here are some other things I've tried:

- Commenting out the call to `enqueue_kernel()` causes the program to succeed.
- Adding a line that sets `heap[0]` to any number causes the host-side program to reflect that change. So I know that it's not a problem with how I'm feeding the arguments in
- Modifying the `if` statement so that it reads something impossible like `if(get_global_id(0) == 6000)` *still* causes the error. This tells me that the error is not caused by `enqueue_kernel()` executing (I verified `get_global_size(0) == 1`), but merely that it exists in the program at all.
- Modifying the `if` statement to `if(0)` *does* make the error not happen.
- Making it so `childKernel()` actually does something does not make the error go away.

I am not really sure what to try next. I know my device supports OpenCL 2.0. My device is an AMD Radeon R9 380 graphics card. I do not have access to any other OpenCL 2.0 capable hardware to test it on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this one out. This issue happened because I did not create a device-side queue (one with the flags of `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE | CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE | CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE_DEFAULT`).